# How to read xml response with python requests library?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, python-requests

Currently I've been working on writing a web service which should take response from 'Goodreads" api and produce something.
This is the xml response I got using "requests" library.

```
 <GoodreadsResponse>
<Request></Request>
<search>
    <results>
        <work>
            <best book>
               <title>sometitle</title>
                   <author>
                       <name>somename</name>  
                   </author>
            </best book>  
        </work>

    </results>
</search>
</GoodreadsResponse>
```

How to use xml parser to parse this response structure ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `import xml` and `help(xml)`

Comment: You can use BeautifulSoup library, it has intuitive interface https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/